# Changed power brake booster and drum brake rebuild and now the brake pedal sometimes gets stuck down while driving

Tags: brakes, brake-booster, brake-pedal, drum-brakes

**What I did:**

I have a 1997 GMC Jimmy that I replaced the power brake booster and rebuilt the rear drum brakes (new brake shoes, springs, and wheel cylinders).  I bled the rear drums since I replaced the wheel cylinders.  I did not have to remove any lines from the master cylinder in order to remove the power brake booster / install the new one so I did not bleed the front brakes. I also topped off the brake fluid in the master cylinder.

**The problem:**

When I took it for a test drive, every once in a while the brake pedal would stick to where I pushed it to and there would be a squealing kind of noise coming from the area of the brake booster.  I took the car on about 5 test drives and every time it would do it at least once.  Sometimes it would happen when I slam on the brakes and sometimes it wouldn't.  Sometimes it would happen when I was just pressing regularly and again, other times it wouldn't.  The easiest way I found to get the pedal to come back up to normal position was to put the car in park and pump the pedal.

**My question:**

What could be causing this?  Is the power brake booster that I was sent defective or is it something else?  Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This sounds most like there is an issue with the master cylinder and/or the booster mechanism. I couldn't tell you what it is, exactly, but that's where I'd look first for answers. Maybe someone on here has experienced this type of issue before and can give you a better clue than I can.

Comment: Sounds like a defective booster or incorrect installation.

Comment: I know it's a pain but sounds like a wheel cylinder isn't retracting back into the bore. Air in the lines doesn't cause a pedal to stick down. Isolate the side that's sticking and check it. Remanufactured cylinders tend to be garbage, are they OEM?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! I have another booster on the way so I can figure out if it is the booster or something else. Also @geoO the wheel cylinders are new AcDelco (OEM for GM).

Comment: If you solve it come back you can make an answer to your own question and then upvote it. Pictures would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was a faulty power brake booster. I removed and returned the first one that Cardone sent me and installed the second one. It's been about a week and a half and there is no longer an issue leading me to believe that the first booster that they sent me was defective.

Comment: I get a lot of remanufactured parts with defects. It's a scandal and a trap for the unwary DIYer. Sometimes, not always, it's best to buy from the dealer, because their parts go will into warranteed cars, and is likely to be a specific, operational part. Not some no-name core with a "universal" fit that is used to replace a group of OEM part numbers. Cardone actually on my "junk" list.